# See current rotation without playing

Tags: splatoon

Since there are always only a limited set of maps playable at a time for public online battles, I'd like to know which maps are in the current rotation without booting my Wii U and waiting for Marie and Callie to "announce" it.

Is there a way to find out online which maps (and game mode for Ranked Battles) are currently available for online battles?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's two ways to do this.

The more "official" way is to log on to the official [splatoon leaderboards site](https://splatoon.nintendo.net/schedule), then go to the Stage Info tab on the left (the purple one) if you aren't there already. This will tell you the current maps and ranked mode as well as ones in the future.

The other way is to use [this unofficial site](https://splatoon.ink/) that pulls data off of the first site. It displays the current map rotation and current mode, as well as a countdown until the rotation changes, but does not show future rotations. (Also there's a button on the top left to turn off the embedded music!)

**Update:**
[Here](http://splatooniverse.com/) is another site that shows the rotation. Unlike the site I posted above, this one also shows future maps!

Comment: That leaderboard site would be great if it was available in English.

Comment: Just something for Nintendo, I never heard anything about such a website from official channels. I found a Chrome plugin that translates the website so I added it to your post if you don't mind. The other website is useful too, thanks.

Comment: Looks like they finally translated the leaderboard site to english so I updated my answer and removed your chrome extension link.

Comment: Anyone know a current site for this?  These are all offline or converted to splatoon 2.

Comment: @msouth Try asking that as a new question, since that's for a different game.

Comment: @Pyritie this question is about splatoon 1 (see "without booting my Wii U" and the date of the post) and so is mine.  The linked sites in the answer are either offline or they've been converted to show the upcoming stages for splatoon 2.

Comment: @msouth Oh I see. I don't know of any others. I'd be surprised if any were still going, considering even nintendo doesn't really "support" splatoon 1 any more.

Comment: @Pyritie Well, *someone* is keeping those servers up :).  But you're right, it's not the current hotness or anything.  All I'm really wondering is if I can find the mechanism they used to get it;if I can find that out, I can set something up myself.  I guess I need to learn to snoop my own network :D.